# How to compare mixed effect model with one random effect to one without random effect in R

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

Essentially comparing:

```
glm1 = glmer(Mortality ~ CCI + PatientRace + PatientSex + age_cat + (CCI | FacilityIdentifier), 
             data = tmp, family = binomial, 
             control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 1)
```

to

```
m1 = glm(Mortality ~ CCI + PatientRace + PatientSex + age_cat, 
         family=binomial, data = tmp)
```

To determine if the random effect is a significant contributor, hopefully to show that each facility doesn't have varying practices in measuring CCI that may affect interpretation of mortality. Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Why not just bootstrap confidence intervals and see if that of the random effect's variance includes zero (non-significant) or not (significant)? You can simply do this with `confint(glm1, method = "boot")`.

Comment: @amoeba woops, didn't mean to include that